# Flutter Cupertino Picker errors out on first item if picker isn't scrolled

Tags: flutter, cupertinopicker

The app I'm building uses a Cupertino Picker that shows a list of items to select, in this case the names of the US States. The first item defaults to the first item in the list ('ak'), when the button to select the item is pressed, the app errors out. This only happens with the first item, when the picker isn't scrolled. If the picker is scrolled and the user goes back to the first item, it works fine.

```
class StateSelectScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'state_select_screen';

  @override
  _StateSelectScreenState createState() => _StateSelectScreenState();
}

class _StateSelectScreenState extends State<StateSelectScreen> {

  String selectedState = 'ak';
  bool showSpinner = false;

 DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String state in statesList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          USStates.getName(state).toUpperCase(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        value: state,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      dropdownColor: Colors.black26,
      autofocus: true,
      focusColor: Colors.black26,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: k30PointFont,
      ),
      value: selectedState,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedState = value;
          getStateData();
        });
      },
    );
  }

  CupertinoPicker iOSPicker() {
    List<Text> pickerItems = [];
    for (String state in statesList) {
      pickerItems.add(Text(USStates.getName(state.toUpperCase())));
    }

    return CupertinoPicker(
      backgroundColor: kCupertinoPickerBackgroundColor,
      itemExtent: kCupertinoPickerItemExtent,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
        setState(() {
          selectedState = USStates.getName(statesList[selectedIndex]);
          getStateData();
        });
      },
      children: pickerItems,
    );
  }

Map<String, dynamic> selectedStateData = {};
  bool isWaiting = false;

  void getStateData() async {
    isWaiting = true;
    try {
      var stateData = await GetData().getStateData(selectedState);
      isWaiting = false;
      setState(() {
        selectedStateData = stateData;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStateData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(kAppBarTitle),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kStateSelectScreenFlexEdgeInsetsTop, bottom: kStateSelectScreenFlexEdgeBottom),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: kHeroTag,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset(kHeroImageAsset),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: kStateSelectScreenContainerHeight,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kStateSelectScreenContainerPaddingBottom),
                    child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown(),
                  ),
                  BottomButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return ResultsScreen(
                              covidData: selectedStateData,
                              location: selectedState,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    buttonTitle: kCheckStateResultsButtonTitle,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: kHeight15,
                  ),
                  BottomButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, MenuScreen.id);
                    },
                    buttonTitle: kMainMenuButtonTitle,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe set init state

Comment: This is what I have for initState():

`  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStateData();
  }
`

Comment: post whole code

Comment: I have modified my original post.

Comment: whats error, paste error pls

Comment: `The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("cases")`

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your problem, but don't see any error.
https://codepen.io/flakerimi/pen/poRywLZ

You said `when the button to select the item is pressed, the app errors out.`

Which button ? I don't see any

I have added `scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 1),` but I don't think thats the case.

```
return CupertinoPicker(
      scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 1),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      itemExtent: 30,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
        setState(() {
          selectedState = statesList[selectedIndex];
          print(selectedState);
        });
      },
      children: pickerItems,
    );
```

Comment: I added the scroll controller and still have the issue. 

I didn't include the widget code, but I will. When the button is pressed it moves to another screen.

Comment: Which button? I dont see a button, can you fork my codepen or create one with your data, render whole view